# 12.04 on VirtualBox -No internet access on Guest OS

Tags: 12.04, networking, virtualbox, internet, virtualization

I have Windows 7 as my Host OS which has wired Ethernet working. My guest OS on VirtualBox is Ubuntu 12.04. The problem is that I cannot browse.

I have:

1. Enabled sharing on Windows;
2. Have used NAT, Bridged Adapter etc ( all possible combinations);
3. With NAT, used PCnet-FAST II (Am79c973) combination.

Ubuntu says "**connected to wired ethernet1**" but I cannot access websites.

**VirtualBox Host-Only Network in the Network and Sharing center shows that I don't have IPV4 and IPV6 connectivity.**

Meaning I don't have DHCP configured.
Strangely I have DNS address correct in the Ubuntu properties.

Comment: Please post the content of /etc/resolv.conf on the Ubuntu guest machine.

Answer (score 5):

For Internet access you can change network option to this :

[image]

I had this problem and solve with this option.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have this issue of networking, try this.

Choose **Bridged Adapter** as said before boot your guest os (i.e ubuntu).

Try to **ping** any website from terminal. If you get '*unknown host*' as the reply, the issue probably lies at **DNS** level.

To fix it, go and check if '**/etc/resolv.conf**' file exits and its contents. You should have atleast one name server entered by Network manager inside the file.

Note: There is also a directory called /etc/resolvconf. we are not concerned about it.

If the above file does not exist, do create one.

```
$sudo vim /etc/resolv.conf
```

and then enter this

```
nameserver <YOUR_DNS_IP_ADDRESS>
```

Save the file (press escape followed by : followed by wqa)

Hope internet works now.