# No internet on Virtualbox (Windows 7 as guest, Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS as host)

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, windows-7, internet

I've searched all over the net and found an interesting post about it on [No internet connection on Virtualbox (Windows 7 as guest, ubuntu 13.04 as host)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363003/no-internet-connection-on-virtualbox-windows-7-as-guest-ubuntu-13-04-as-host/781333#781333). But unfortunately this did not work for VirtualBox Version **5.0.20** r106931. It worked before but suddenly the Internet stopped working :( I only have **eth0** as **Bridged Adapter** and i used the **HWaddr** value from **ifconfig** for the MAC address. Please help... maybe it has something to do with my purging off the "unity" desktop environment and installing the xfce xubuntu desktop environment.

Comment: You have internet on Ubuntu (host) but not on your Window 7 (guest)?

Comment: Yes but i just resolved it!! :D I noticed there was a refresh button next to the MAC address field in network settings. i clicked that a few times tried with NAT and then again Bridged adapter, now it works again :D but i still don't understand why i suddenly had lost internet connection. well the nxt time this happens i'll just refresh the MAC address :D

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie - Then please add an answer & accept it so this question won't live on in the unanswered area :)

Comment: Oh sorry i didn't know how to close this thread. But just posted an answer, but i can only "accept" answer in 2 days lol :)

Comment: Internet is lost again after restarting host and refreshing the MAC address did not work anymore :(

Comment: Ok but it works if you refresh it several times and restart several times, that makes no sense. I guess i can live with that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: Click the refresh button next to the MAC address field in network settings' advance options to create a new MAC address. You have to refresh it SEVERAL TIMES! WTF