# Unable to access internet through guest OS using bridged adapter

Tags: networking, virtualbox, internet

I have referred [No internet connection on Virtualbox (Windows 7 as guest, ubuntu 13.04 as host)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363003/no-internet-connection-on-virtualbox-windows-7-as-guest-ubuntu-13-04-as-host) question for this problem.

I have been attempting to gain internet access in my guest OS using the configurations defined in the following screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

In my initial attempt, I managed to gain access to internet using the above configurations but all of a sudden the connection was lost and had been absent since then.

I am using eth0 since I am using a wired connection in my host.

Comment: Restart your system first, and if persists then please change your _promiscuous mode_ to _Allow VMs_ and let see if it improves.

Comment: What's the output of `ifconfig` and `ip route` on the guest system?

Comment: I did try both _Allow VMs_ and _Allow All_. No improvement can be seen.

Comment: In the output of ifconfig, eth0 inet address is referred to as 192.168.1.3 which is effectively what we expect from using the Bridged Adapter I believe and ip route result is '192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link metric 100'.