# VM cannot connect to the Internet via a bridged adapter

Tags: networking, virtualbox

After setting up my Ubuntu 16.04 Server as a virtual machine on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS host machine, I am unable to connect to the Internet from the VM. I have followed every step mentioned in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/424368). However the start phase keeps running forever :

[image: Server Start Screenshot]

My configuration (enp0s25 is my host's wired network adapter connected to the Internet):

[image: Host Configuration]

How may I fix this issue please?

Comment: do you have a router serving dhcp between you and your isp? if you connect staigth to your isp using pppoe then you have to make a bridge to your vm

Comment: Yes there is my home router that serves as a dhcp server as well for my LAN.

Comment: how was the adapter when you installed the os? NAT? not attached? you could change the adapter type for intel ones...

Comment: It was Not Attached. Yes I have intel adapter types.

Comment: try changing back to not attached see if it works; also when bridged try changing the adapter type; try all 5 of them